# Jupyter kernel dies while reading file

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter

I am reading a 22.2 GB csv file to a pandas df in a Jupyter notebook on an EC2 instance but I keep getting this error:

[image]

The instance is a t3 2x large instance and while reading the file, the CPU utilization is 13.4% and the total volume size is 60 GB
I am not sure what is causing this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: t3.2xlarge only has 32GB of RAM. Unlikely but possible that 22.2GB csv can surpass 30GB when read in memory.

Comment: @QuangHoang So is there any other way I can read it?

Comment: I'd recommend Pyspark. if you have access to databricks you can mount an s3 bucket and use that as a storage account

Comment: My rule of thumb has been a factor of 2 of the csv size. Especially if you have a lot of long string data (addresses, 20-char alphanumeric IDs) the memory usage of pandas can get pretty heavy, and 2x might be a severe underestimate. Easy to create some samples and check how bad it gets for object with `df.memory_usage(deep=True)`